# VBA - Delete Checkboxes and Unlink from Cells

Tags: excel, vba

I found a macro here (https://ccm.net/faq/37428-excel-vba-how-to-create-multiple-checkboxes) that will create checkboxes in the selected range - which is great - but now I would like to do the opposite, which is delete the checkboxes in the specified range.

Here is the code to **create** the checkboxes:

```
Sub Insert_chkbx_Link_Cell()
    Dim rngCel As Range
    Dim ChkBx As CheckBox

    For Each rngCel In Selection
        With rngCel.MergeArea.Cells
            If .Resize(1, 1).Address = rngCel.Address Then
                Set ChkBx = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(.Left, .Top, .Width, .Height)
                With ChkBx
                    .Value = xlOff
                    .LinkedCell = rngCel.MergeArea.Cells.Address
                    With .Border
                    End With
                End With
            End If
        End With
    Next rngCel
End Sub
```

Here is a sub that will "unlink/unassign" the checkboxes from the cells:

```
Sub Un_Assign()
    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        For Each CheckBox In sht.CheckBoxes
            CheckBox.OnAction = ""
        Next CheckBox
    Next sht
End Sub
```

The problem with this is that it doesn't do it for the specified range AND it will do it for every worksheet.

So I have changed the macro that creates the checkboxes, to one that **deletes** them:

```
Sub Remove_chkbx_Unlink_Cell()
    Dim rngCel As Range
    Dim ChkBx As CheckBox

    For Each rngCel In Selection
        With rngCel.MergeArea.Cells
            If .Resize(1, 1).Address = rngCel.Address Then
                ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Delete
            End If
        End With
    Next rngCel
End Sub
```

Again, this works great, but it deletes every checkbox on the sheet.

So I added a `for each` loop within the `if` statement and tried to specify a range:

```
Sub Remove_chkbx_Unlink_Cell()
    Dim rngCel As Range
    Dim ChkBx As CheckBox

    For Each rngCel In Selection
        With rngCel.MergeArea.Cells
            If .Resize(1, 1).Address = rngCel.Address Then
                For Each ChkBx In rngCel
                    CheckBox.OnAction = ""
                Next ChkBx

                rngCel.CheckBoxes.Delete
            End If
        End With
    Next rngCel
End Sub
```

The problem with this is that I get and error on the `For Each ChkBx In rngCel` line:

> Type mismatch

**EDIT**

There are 6 checkboxes in the image below, the first three are selected and the last 3 are not. Is there a way to delete the unchecked boxes by means of selecting the cells they are linked to?

Below, I have selected the cells of the empty check boxes and much in the same way the I "create" the checkboxes, I would like to delete them: ie, select a range of cells and delete the checkboxes in the range.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To delete CheckBoxes in a specific range you can just loop through all CheckBoxes in a worksheet and delete them if their `.TopLeftCell` intersects ([Application.Intersect Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect)) with your target range.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestDeleteCheckBoxes()
    'delete all CheckBoxes in A1:A10 in Sheet1
    DeleteCheckBoxes ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")
End Sub

Public Sub DeleteCheckBoxes(Target As Range)
    Dim Cbx As CheckBox
    For Each Cbx In Target.Parent.CheckBoxes 'loop through all CheckBoxes on the worksheet
        If Not Intersect(Cbx.TopLeftCell, Target) Is Nothing Then
            Cbx.Delete 'delete it if it intersects with the target range
        End If
    Next Cbx
End Sub
```

Note I wrapped this into a procedure so you can re-use the code on any target range.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I tested your code and it works great, the only issue I have is that I need to give a predefined range selection, however, the checkboxes will not always be in the same range... Is there perhaps a way of doing it by selecting the cells that do have checkboxes and then deleting the checkboxes linked to those cells? The same way in which the checkboxes are created with a "selection".

Comment: *"selecting the cells that do have checkboxes and then deleting the checkboxes linked to those cells?"* wouldn't that delete **all** CheckBoxes on the sheet? Please clarify what exactly you mean. • Or do you mean to delete all CheckBoxes in the selected range?

Comment: Sorry, I have provided a screenshot at the end of the question for my post - Basically, it's what you said now "Or do you mean to delete all CheckBoxes in the selected range"

Comment: Well you can just use `DeleteCheckBoxes Selection` for that.

Comment: Lol, oops I didn't know about that :/.. Thank you very much :)